# PHP magic methods example

Tags: php, magic-methods, zend-certification

I have this question from the Zend PHP study guide and can't find a proper explanation...

```
<?php
    class Magic {
        public $a = "A";
        protected $b = array("a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "c"=>"C");
        protected $c = array(1,2,3);

        public function __get($v) {
            echo "$v,";
            return $this->b[$v];
        }
        public function __set($var, $val) {
            echo "$var: $val,";
            $this->$var = $val;
        }
    }

    $m = new Magic();
    echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c.",";
    $m->c = "CC";
    echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c;
?>
```

According to the guide, solution shall be "`b,c,A,B,C,c: CC,b,c,A,B,C`". I can't figure out why - maybe you do? My intention is that the first call of $m->a would lead to result "a", but that is obviously wrong...

Comment: The code you have provided will output "`b,c,A,B,Cmc: CC,b,c,A,B,C`" (see [this proof](http://codepad.org/ez1rSs63)). Is it a typo or exact content of the guide?

Comment: You're right - small typo. It's correct now http://codepad.org/H91fpj8q

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `__get()` calls `echo`, some data is being outputted before the `echo` outside of the class gets called.

Stepping through the first line with `echo`, this is how it gets executed:

```
$m->a   "A" is concatenated
","     "," is concatenated
$m->b   "b," is echoed, "B" is concatenated
","     "," is concatenated
$m->c   "c," is echoed, "C" is concatenated
"m"     "," is concatenated
```

At this point, `b,c,` has already been `echo`ed, and the string with the value of `A,B,Cm` is now displayed.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. However, if that one comes up in the exam... :)

Thanks to y'all!

Comment: @JanPetzold:  Not a problem. Best of luck!

Comment: @TimCooper,
`$m->c = "CC";`
We already have _protected_ variable with same name here.
So, how should this behave in context of visibility?

If it overwrites value of protected variable `c`, then isn't it a loop hole for protected/private variables?
If not then, the statement: `$this->$var = $val;` seems to create public variable with same name already defined as protected.
Is that possible?

Also, after this statement: `$m->c = "CC";`, when we access `$m->c` again, PHP calls `__get` again as if `c` has no public visibility.
Does that mean `$this->$var = $val;` was not executed successfully?