# PHP variable visibility and behaviour with magic method

Tags: php, visibility, magic-methods, zend-certification

This question is related to: [PHP magic methods example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451116/php-magic-methods-example)

I've asked this question in comment in accepted answer but I guess, it has not been noticed so I have to create this question.

```
<?php
    class Magic {
        public $a = "A";
        protected $b = array(
            "a"=>"A", 
            "b"=>"B", 
            "c"=>"C"
        );
        protected $c = array(1,2,3);

        public function __get($v) {
            echo "$v,";
            return $this->b[$v];
        }

        public function __set($var, $val) {
            echo "$var: $val,";
            $this->$var = $val;
        }
    }

    $m = new Magic();
    echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c.",";
    $m->c = "CC";
    echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c;
?>
```

Output:
`b,c,A,B,C,c: CC,b,c,A,B,C`

`$m->c = "CC";` Here we already have protected variable with same name.
So, how should this should behave in context of visibility?

If it overwrites value of protected variable `c`, then isn't it a loop hole for protected/private variables? (I guess that would not be the case)

If not then, the statement: `$this->$var = $val;` seems to create public variable with same name already defined as protected.
Is that possible?

Also, after this statement: `$m->c = "CC";`, when we access `$m->c` again, PHP calls `__get` again as if `c` has no public visibility.
Does that mean `$this->$var = $val;` has no life time for immediate next statement? (I guess that would also not be the case)

Can anybody please explain, it should behaves in such cases and how it gave such output?

Comment: Related Atricle: [All properties should be private!!](http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/1cb6fc8170b6a8c8eb04); Read through Google Translation.

Comment: Usually, the whole point of magic methods is to expose protected variables and maybe use some logic on the way. You would not need them for any plain public variables. So, yes it is working as intended! If you dont want to expose them, do not use magic methods or implement your own filter in those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `c` is being changed by the methods only.  While it is protected, the magic methods expose it.

If you look at this example:

```
class Magic
{
    protected $b = 'B';

    public function __get($v)
    {
        return 'C';
    }

    public function __set($v, $val)
    {
        $this->$v = $val;
    }
}

$magic->b = 'D';
echo $magic->b; // Outputs: C
```

The first call does set property `b` to `D`, however because the getter is hard-coded to return `C`, the `protected` access modifier is still respected.

EDIT.

Another use of magic getters/setters is accessing collections.  This example demonstrates their flexibility:

```
class Magic
{
    private $properties = array();

    public function __get($key)
    {
        if(isset($this->properties[$key])) {
            return $this->properties[$key];
        }
    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->properties[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function dump($return = false)
    {
        if($return) {
            return print_r($this->properties, true);
        } else {
            print_r($this->properties);
        }
    }
}

$magic = new Magic();

$magic->a = '123';
$magic->b = '456';
$magic->c = '789';

echo '<pre>';

echo sprintf('A: %s%s', $magic->a, PHP_EOL);
echo sprintf('B: %s%s', $magic->b, PHP_EOL);
echo sprintf('C: %s%s', $magic->c, PHP_EOL);

echo PHP_EOL;

echo $magic->dump(true);
```

Output:

```
A: 123
B: 456
C: 789

Array
(
    [a] => 123
    [b] => 456
    [c] => 789
)
```

They are only functions and therefore follow the same rules, only difference is the method in which they are invoked.

Comment: `public function __get($v) {
   return $this->$v;
 }`

What would this return?

Comment: It would return the value of whatever property you asked for, if it exists.  This is because the `__get` method belongs to the class, and therefore has access to all protected properties.

Comment: @CoolZeroInfinity Updated answer, hopefully it should shed a bit more light on what those methods are.

Answer (score 1):

Your getter and setter each apply to different variables.

The getter accesses a element of the property $b
The setter accesses the specified property directly.

Visibility is of no concern here as all of your access happens from methods of the class. So they are able to access public and protected properties without any difference.

Think of a magic function as just a normal function with a strange name. It is the same as accessing them this way:

```
$m->__get("a");
$m->__set("c", "CC");
```

Comment: ah! yes, my bad :-(
in this example, there is no visibility concern.